# Acknowledged kombu message is not removed from RabbitMQ queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-asyncio, kombu

I am trying to create a Python script that waits for a message on a RabbitMQ queue to start a task in a subprocess. During task execution, the script continues to consume another queue for a cancel order that would stop the task.

I use `kombu` package to handle interactions with RabbitMQ. I call `message.ack()` when the task terminates (whether normally or because of cancellation).

Despite the call to `message.ack()`, the start message is not removed from the queue (I can tell by using `rabbitmqctl`). This causes the message to be redelivered even if the task ran to completion.

I created [a sample repository to show the problem](https://github.com/Nautigsam/rabbitmq-ack-test). The README file shows the reproduction steps.

I do not know where the problem could be. I realize there are many moving parts but this is a slightly simplified version of a real project with its own constraints (like the Python version being fixed to 3.8). I am open to any suggestion to make a better use of `kombu` or `asyncio` because I am quite new to AMQP and async Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the cause of my problem. Actually there were two causes:

1. I did not set channels when creating the Consumers, so they were both using the same channel. Since I had set `noAck=True` for the "stop" consumer, calling `message.ack()` had no effect. The strange thing is that `noAck=True` should have caused the ACK to be sent at reception, even for start message, but it was not.
2. I got mistaken with the closure of the `on_done` callback. I thought the closure contained the `message` at the moment it was created, but it wasn't. Instead, it contained the last message received, i.e. the "stop" message. I'm quite new to Python so I am not sure how closures work. I assumed it worked like JavaScript but it seems not. Overall I stored the message when creating the task, gave it back as an argument to the `on_done` callback and it worked.

I could not find the solution until I used the debugger to inspect the execution step by step. This shows once again the superiority of the debugger when troubleshooting. I should have gone with it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `message.ack()` is called on the "cancel" `message`.

Fix it by rebinding `message` in `on_done()` callback:

```py
    while True:
        message = await async_queue.get()

        body = message.decode()
        ...

        if body == "start":
            work_in_progress = loop.run_in_executor(...)

            # def on_done(_):                 # Change this
            def on_done(_, message=message):  # to this
                ...
                message.ack()
                ...

            work_in_progress.add_done_callback(on_done)

        elif body == "cancel":
            ...

        ...
```

Note that "cancel" `message.ack()` does not ack "start" `message` because:

1. `multiple` is not passed, as in `message.ack(multiple=True)`.
   Doc: [docs.celeryq.dev/.../reference/kombu.message.html#kombu.message.Message.ack](https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/kombu/en/stable/reference/kombu.message.html#kombu.message.Message.ack)
2. Specifying the "cancel" `Consumer` as `no_ack=True` causes "cancel" `message.ack()` to early return.
   Source: [github.com/celery/kombu/blob/c03335e/kombu/message.py#L114-L121](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/c03335e/kombu/message.py#L114-L121)